# Find a set of parametric equations for the line passing through (0,1,3) that is perpendicular to the plane x+y+z=2 and perpendicular to the line

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a set of parametric equations for the line passing through $(0,1,3)$ that is perpendicular to the plane $x+y+z=2$ and perpendicular to the line
$x = 1+t$ ; $y = 1-t $; $z = 2t$.

I am stuck at perpendicular to the plane $x+y+z=2$, I don't know what to do. Is the way to solve it same with parallel to the plane ?

If I'm not mistaken  in parallel to the plane we use $x(t) + y(t) + z(t) = D = constant$

Can I use that in perpendicular to plane or there is another way?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Hint…perpendicular to the plane is the vector $$\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right)$$

This is enough information to find the equation of the line because the direction is now determined and the fixed point is given.

The direction of the given line is $$\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-1\\2\end{matrix}\right)$$

The line you want can’t be perpendicular to this as well.

Is it perhaps that you are looking for the equation of a **plane** perpendicular to the given plane and line?

Comment: I want to find the equations of a line passing through (0,1,3) that perpendicular to the plane and alo perpendicular to the line x = 1+ t ; y = 1-t ; z = 2t. Is it possible?

Comment: There is a unique line through $(0,1,3)$ and whose direction is parallel to the plane’s normal, but this line is not perpendicular to the other line you mention.